# What is the guarantee of uniqueness of shortid?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to include a field in Mongodb document called myId. I am using [shortid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid). I am wondering, in case of big data, like millions of documents in a collections:

1. What's the guarantee that the `shortid` will be always unique and never ever be repeated for any other document?
2. What keeps a track of the generated ids?
3. What are the chances of the id been repeated?

Comment: I'm assuming it's pretty improbable that `shortid` will create duplicate IDs but it could happen. You should have a unique index on your column in MongoDB to assure that you can't insert a record using an ID that exists. That way if the insert fails you can generate a new ID and insert again. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Comment: from the npm-page of shortid: `By default 7-14 url-friendly characters: A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _-`  that means something between 2^42 and 2^85 possible combinations; or as a decimal, up to a number in the lower 26 digits (approximately 19000000000000000000000000 possible combinations). Chances of an id been repeated: `Apps can be restarted any number of times without any chance of repeating an id.` That's a pretty bold statement. **Edit:** after a first glance at the RNG in the source, well i'm devastated. Have to check out how these are used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `What's the guarantee that the shortid will be always unique and never ever be repeated for any other document`

to cut a long story short: these shortids are pretty much just "hashed" timestamps. Not unix timestamps, their own breed, but non the less not much more than timestamps.

All that bling with Random is pretty much that, just bling.

As long as all these shortids are generated on the same computer *(a single thread)* with the same seed, collisions are impossible.

> What keeps a track of the generated ids?

A counter that gets incremented when a you request ids to fast, so that the same timestamp is hit. This counter is reset to 0 as soon as a new timestamp is reached.

There's nothing significant, that is really random in there.

> What are the chances of the id been repeated?

during usage, little to non existant.

As far as I can tell, the only two things that *may* lead to a collision are

- changing the seed for the prng (leads to a new alphabet, so that newer dates may be encoded to ids that already have been generated with a different seed; although not very likely, but possible)
- generating ids on multiple threads/machines because the counter is not synced.

**Summary:** I'd nag about pretty much everything in that code, but even as it is, it does the job, reliable. And I've told you the limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Shortid generates a random 64 bit id. This is done in multiple step, but the base of it is this pseudo-random function:

```
function getNextValue() {
    seed = (seed * 9301 + 49297) % 233280;
    return seed/(233280.0);
}
```

To generate the same id twice, this function has to return the same exact values in the same exact order **in the same exact second**. This is very rare, but can happen if they reset the timer (based on the comments, they do, but it's still rare).

Comment: No, shortid generates around 20bit of randomness + 40bit predictable hash in a single id. And these two can even be easily distinguished and seperated. And second, this function has (almost) nothing to do with the generated ids. It is only used to shuffle the alphabet (once, at the beginning). And unless you manually seed shortid, even the shuffled alphabet is static, because it always uses the same default seed and this function returns the same values in the same order, always!